# jquery list in a list selector for slideUp

Tags: jquery, nested-lists, slideup, html-lists

i've a list in a list like that

```
 <ul>
  <li>
   <ul>
    <li>something</li>
    <li>something</li>
   </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
   <ul>
    <li>something2</li>
    <li>something2</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

i use the selector (see below) to hide main list's second item but this line hides 1. sublist's second item. I want to hide main list's second item how can i do this?

```
$("#main_menu ul li:eq(1)").slideUp();
```

Comment: lol sorry, i forgot my question. added now.

Comment: What is `#main_menu`?  Is this the direct parent of the main list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this(assuming `ul` is the direct child of `main_menu`).

```
 $("#main_menu > ul > li:eq(1)").slideUp();
```

In your selector `#main_menu ul li` will select all the `li` elements within each `ul` of `main_menu` so you should specify just to search the immediate children by using `>` child selector.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MXZCp/)**

Comment: That works. thanks a lot. i will accept that answer in 4 mins.